# Stopping a service when home button is clicked?

Tags: java, android

I have a service which plays music when the page is loaded, and carries on to all the other pages as it should. It still played when the application was destroyed, so i put a onDestroy method and an onResume method.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent ServiceMusic = new Intent(this, BackgroundMusic.class);
    stopService(ServiceMusic);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Intent ServiceMusic = new Intent(this, BackgroundMusic.class);
    startService(ServiceMusic);
}
```

Now the problem is when the user clicks the home button the service carries on, so I implemented a onPause and it worked fine, just when the user goes to another page the music restarts.

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Intent ServiceMusic = new Intent(this, BackgroundMusic.class);
    stopService(ServiceMusic);
}
```

How can i overcome this so the music carries on playing when going through the application but when the Home Button is clicked i pause the service?

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the code that is in individual activities and use the `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` mechanism in your application subclass. This will allow you to keep the code in one place and be smarter about starting and stopping your service.

Be aware that with these callbacks, you'll be notified that an Activity has stopped before another activity has started, so you will need some kind of delay when you decide to stop your service. You can use a handler with a delayed runnable to account for this issue.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)